# '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid SQL data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)' Issue

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

Like on title Im having this problem on this line.

```
mycursor.execute("UPDATE slot SET plaka=?,girisTarih=?,girisSaat=?,musaitlik=?,  WHERE slotAd=?",plaka1,girisTarih,girisSaat,musaitlik,slotAd)
```

musaitlik = true/false(0-1)
slotAd = A1

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import easyocr
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageTk
import os
import pyodbc
import datetime
import numpy as np
import imutils
import random

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-L3245F\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Database=CarPark;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;''autocommit=True')



def giris(plaka1):
    global plaka
    
    print("girdi")
    mycursor = conn.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT plaka from slot where plaka=?",(plaka1))
    kontrol=False
    for x in mycursor:
        if (x[0]==plaka1):
            kontrol=True
    if(kontrol):
        print("Bu Araç Otoparktadır")
    else:
        mycursor = conn.cursor()
        girisTarih = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
        girisSaat = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
        musaitlik = 0
        mycursor.execute("SELECT slotAd FROM slot WHERE musaitlik='1'")
        slotAd = mycursor.fetchone()
        mycursor.execute("UPDATE slot SET plaka=?,girisTarih=?,girisSaat=?,musaitlik=?,  WHERE slotAd=?",plaka1,girisTarih,girisSaat,musaitlik,slotAd)
        conn.commit()
        print(mycursor.rowcount, "Giriş Yapildi.")
        plaka=""

tantuni = "52 AT 533"
giris(tantuni)
```

Comment: Try `slotAd = mycursor.fetchval()` instead of `slotAd = mycursor.fetchone()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
slotAd = mycursor.fetchval()
```

instead of

```
slotAd = mycursor.fetchone().
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: You could have still used latter but remember it returns a tuple of one item not scalar, so index first item to parameterize in `UPDATE` query: `mycursor.fetchone()[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Issue comes down to your attempt to parameterize a sequence/iterable object when passing the return of `fetchone` which does not return one *scalar* value but one *sequence* (i.e., row) of values. If only one column from query is returned then you have a sequence/iterable of one element.

Per the Python's DB-API Specification (PEP 249) of which `pyodbc` largely adheres to, [**`fetchone`**](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#id20) is specified to return (emphasis added):

> Fetch the next row of a query result set, *returning a single sequence*, or None when no more data is available.

Therefore, simply index the first item of sequence/iterable for specific first column value before parameterizing which expects only scalars:

```py
mycursor.execute("SELECT slotAd FROM slot WHERE musaitlik='1'")
slotAd = mycursor.fetchone()[0]

mycursor.execute(
    "UPDATE slot SET plaka=?, girisTarih=?, girisSaat=?, musaitlik=? WHERE slotAd=?",
    plaka1, girisTarih, girisSaat, musaitlik, slotAd
)
conn.commit()
```

---

Per pyodbc docs, [**`fetchval`**](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fetchval) as suggested is characterized as a:

> convenience method returns the first column of the first row if there are results, otherwise it returns None.

which may run either `fetchall()[0][0]` or `fetchone()[0]` under the hood.